# bundle css file in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have some content such as css files in my asp.net mvc4 project. One of this files is that related to jqGrid which it is in:

```
\Content\jquery.jqGrid\ui.jqgrid.css
```

so i could import it using below between the head tags:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui.jqGrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

but i have seen that site.css is imported using bundle technique so i want to do the same so in the BundleConfig.cs under App_Start folder in mvc4 skeleton. I am using below line but it does not work:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("/Content/css").Include("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css"));
```

I guess I need to include because I have an error in my code see below.

In my view I have below:

```
<div id="jqGrid">
    @Html.Partial("../Component/_ComponentGrid")
</div>
```

and I have a javascript file which begins as:

```
function showGrid() {
    $('#_componentGrid').jqGrid({
        caption: paramFromView.Caption, ....
```

In runtime an error is raised: The object does not accept the property or method 'jqGrid'.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

maybe missing "**~**" before '/Content':

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css"));
```

Between `<head>` tag you should call something like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

And error: The object does not accept the property or method 'jqGrid'. It looks that jqGrid .js isn't included...

Answer (score 0):

Work backwards and include the script files directly in your view, then in your layout and then add them to a bundle.

When you are adding them to a bundle you will still have to add that bundle to your view or layout via:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

You can examine via Firebug or it's equivalents to ensure that your bundle / scripts are loading properly.